# mockito doThrow is returning null instead of raising an exception

Tags: java, mockito

We're trying to cause an exception to enter one of our catch blocks.  In order to do this we would like to raise an exception when a post request is made.
Neither options seem to work.

```
   when(mockrestTemplate.postForObject(any(), any(), any())).thenThrow(new RestClientException("OOPS"));  
   doThrow(new RestClientException("OOPS")).when(mockrestTemplate).postForObject(any(), any(), any());
```

If I use doReturn and pass in the expected object in it works as expected, it mocks it properly.

If I try to raise an exception it does not raise an exception, and instead the line executes fully causing a variable to be set to null, as if the mock had returned a null value.

This is the signature of the function being mocked in question is :

```
 public <T> T postForObject(URI url, Object request, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would suggest avoiding the use of `any()` as this can have unexpected behaviour on overloaded methods.

Secondly,

```
when(mockedObject.someMethod(isA(Type.class))).thenThrow(new Exception());
```

should be working for a properly set up mock ... If the exception is not being thrown in the System Under Test on the tested method, try verifying the method is being called (at the end of your unit test)

```
verify(mockedObject).someMethod(isA(Type.class));
```

Comment: You are correct Adam, the *any* was confusing it because the function was overridden and there were multiple signatures using the same function name.

For some reason "verify" is failing to work however, even though I can see that it does generate the exception for me.